# How to set the automatic debug for console application

Tags: c#, .net

I developed on console application. I finished that successfully.My requirement is,that application automatically run in weekly once. I don't know how to set automatic debug.Can you please any one help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "automatic debug"?

Comment: That means weekly once the application should be debug without any external resources

Comment: I'm sorry, but what you're asking doesn't make any sense. It's in the same vein as "How I mine for fish?" If english isn't your native tongue, you might try posting your question in your primary language and see if anyone can translate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a Console application, you will get an executable file `*.exe`. 
You may schedule the `exe` using Operating system scheduling. That way you can specify the time and interval for the application to launch itself. You can't set it to debug through visual studio.

Another way could be to create Windows Service application, but probably you don't need it. Scheduling is a much better option.

You may see this article: [How to schedule a program to run automatically](http://www.techsupportalert.com/how_to_schedule_programs_to_run_automatically.htm).

Comment: Can you suggest some of the link how to schedule the application in operating system. Bcz i don't know abt that

Comment: Okay. I need some examples. Could you please share

Comment: Example ??  and follow the article, point the path to your application exe. Its in debug folder of your application/bin